# configuring cgi-bin using .htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I'm trying to configure a directory as cgi-bin using `.htaccess`, but when I try to access the executables, the files are downloaded. I'm using apache2.2. What is the problem?

My `.htaccess` looks like:

```
# cat www/cgi-bin/.htaccess
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
```

File permissions are

```
# ls -1la www/cgi-bin/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 iun 10 19:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 iun 10 19:18 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    46 iun 10 19:23 .htaccess
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15358 iun 10 19:23 paperload.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12728 iun 10 19:23 papers.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12593 iun 10 19:23 paperview.cgi
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget your dots:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

Make note that you also have to modify the `AllowOverride` directive for that directory to allow your `.htaccess` files to be read.

Don't forget to restart Apache.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex please see additional info.